# Getting python library listed on Google App Engine services page

Tags: google-app-engine

What is the procedure to get your python library to be listed on Google App Engine services page.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Does Google require us to go through some review process, before our library can be listed on the above page. Or is it decided based on the demand of the library itself. (e.g. If Library X is very popular, does Google talk to Library devs and ask them if it is fine to upload that library on the above page)

Comment: anything in pure python is usable now, those just have components that are not I guess so are provided via the app.yaml config. I imagine they review them internally as a memory leak, for example, might be serious in the cloud.

Comment: Do you know what the review process is, or who should I talk to get started on the review process for my library to be listed on the above page

Comment: some of the devs hang around here.  beyond that I cannot help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those libraries are considered widely used.  If you want to get a particular library listed, you probably should start by filing a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

You'll need to convince Google that whatever library you're adding is widely used.  Essentially, you need to convince people to star the request after you've created it.

Most libraries don't need to be included with the App Engine SDK.  Just provide the source and let people include it in the code in their own projects.